# Вопрос про ветки в git

Tags: git, github

Обязательно ли должны совпадать названия веток в локальном репозитории и веток в удаленном репозитории?

Comment: Нет, не обязательно

Comment: То есть это нужно для большего понимания что с чем связано?

Comment: Ветки гита - это ветвление кода общего репозитория, однако вам никто не мешает создавать свои ветки с любым названием и пушить данные в ветки существующего репозитория. Одно ограничение: У вас не должно быть личных веток, пересекающихся по названию с ветками репозитория

Comment: @SwaD, последнее предложение вообще непонятно.

Comment: @SwaD, нет такого ограничения. Они в разных «деревьях» живут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет.

- Названия веток могут быть любыми.
- Одной ветки origin'а может соответствовать несколько локальных и наоборот.
- Локальной ветке могут вообще не соответствовать никакие удалённые.
- Для управления соответствием веток может использоваться: `git push -u` (она же [`git push --set-upstream ...`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---set-upstream)), [`git branch --set-upstream-to=...`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---set-upstream-toltupstreamgt) и [`git branch --unset-upstream`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---unset-upstream).

Comment: спасибо, я понял

Comment: @jonathan, тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.